# How does the client knows which transport protocol to use?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

Let's assume that I start a server at one of the computers in my private network (192.168.10.10:9900).

Now when making a request from some other computer in the same network, how does the client computer (OS?) knows which protocol to use / which protocol the server follows ? [TCP or UDP]

EDIT: As mentioned in the answers, I was basically looking for a default protocol which will be used by the client in the absence of any transport protocol information.

Comment: The client application tells the OS when it creates the socket. There is no default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP / UDP protocols work at the transport layer level (TCP / IP MODEL) and its main difference is that TCP has a method to ensure the arrival of messages while UDP is lighter because of its virtue is to be faster in Information delivery. **The use of one protocol or another is always defined by the application that will use it.**

So the reference you put on the private server with ip: port 192.168.10.10:9900 is very vague to be more precise we could say that we have an Apache web server running on the ip: port 192.168.10.10:9900 (the port for default is 80 when installing the server, but it can be changed in the configuration).

Now the web servers (apache, IIS, etc.) work using the TCP protocol because when a client (computer, cell phone, etc.) consults a page through a browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc.), the ideal thing is that all the website and not just some pieces. This is why this type of servers chose and use this protocol in the first instance since they seek that in the end the result is that the user obtains the complete page regardless of whether a few more milliseconds are sacrificed in the validations involved in using TPC.

Now going to the client side. The user when visiting a web page from any browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc.) will use TCP since this protocol is already configured in the browser to send the query messages and subsequently receive the messages with the same form Website information.

Now this behavior is going to be repeated for any client / server application. For example, to change the type of application on the UDP side, we can observe the operation of DHCP services which are used to receive an IP when connecting any device to a Wi-Fi network. In this case, this service seeks to be as fast as possible (instead of the most reliable) since you want the device to connect as quickly as possible to the network, so use the UDP protocol and in this case any equipment when connecting To a WIFI network you will send your messages using this protocol.

Finally, if you want to know promptly about the type of TCP / UDP protocol used by a specific application, you can search on the [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) application which allows you to scan the messages that leave the device or show the protocol used in the different layers of the application.

Comment: I understand about TCP and UDP. It's just that I was confused about how does the client makes a decision in the absence of an explicit/derived information. Based on answers, it seems it completely depends upon the client program about which default protocol it wants to follow (which is almost always TCP)

Comment: Applications always at some point in their configuration will have defined the protocol to use since when the service was designed (dhcp, http, etc.) it was necessary to decide if the messages were to be reliable or fast.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason any client would make a request to your server, so why would it care what protocol it follows? Clients don't just randomly connect to things to see if there's a server there. So it doesn't make any difference to any client.

Comment: I mean what if I am the client. I am just trying to understand the flow here. Does it mean every client should have some existing information about the protocol expected by the server ? Or is this information found out by a standard query mechanism ?

Comment: @indiansher I don't understand what you mean by "i am the client". What are you? Are you a computer? A program? Or what? Do you mean you are some particular program that implements some particular protocol? If so, why do you need to know what protocol to use? What exactly is the scenario you are imagining?

Comment: Okay let me break this down. Lets assume you started a server, and the only thing you told me is that you have a server (lets assume webserver) running on <ip:port>. Now when I make a request for some page, how does my computer knows what transport protocols does your server follows ?

Comment: @indiansher I don't understand what you mean by "when I make a request for some page". Do you mean you launch a browser? If so, browsers know to use HTTP because they're browsers. There's no way to "make a request for some page" without knowing it's a page that you're after, and that means HTTP over TCP because that's how web pages work.

Comment: @indiansher How did you know it was a web page and not a teamspeak server? Did I tell you?

Comment: Lets assume I am making a curl request. `curl -XGET 192.168.10.10:9900/test-page`. So do I have to specify http (an application protocol ? ). And even if I do so, how do I know if the underlying transport protocol is tcp/udp ? [Unless there is a 1-1 mapping between application protocols and transport protocols, which I think is not the case]

Comment: The curl program will attempt to guess the protocol if you don't specify it. In this case, it guesses HTTP over TCP.

Comment: Okay. I am actually looking for an example where TCP/UDP both might work (but the server chose to follow just one). For example, SNMP or LDAP. All I want to understand is that do I need the information <ip, port and transport protocol> before making the first request ?

Comment: @indiansher You may or may not depending on all the circumstances. You need enough information to know what program to use as the client and whatever information that client needs. It is entirely dependent on the details of the exact situation. For VNC, for example, you may need to know lots of protocol details including what kind of encryption or compression is being used.

Comment: Got it, Thank you @david-schwartz. I didn't know about VNC. So, it completely depends upon the situation. However, in the absence of any explicitly mentioned protocol, by default TCP is used by curl (one example of client application). And if the server doesn't understand TCP, the request will fail. This is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the client computer will use the TCP protocol as default. If you start the server using UDP protocol mode, then when you use `curl -XGET 192.168.10.10:9900/test-page`, it will give you back an `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.10.10 port 9900: Connection refused` error. You can try it, use the `nc -lvp 9900 -u`, it will give you that result.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. This is what I wanted to know. The default assumption is TCP.

Comment: curl uses TCP by default. Maybe some other client program might use UDP by default ?

Comment: No, most of client programs are using TCP by default, because all the server programs are using TCP by default. The default of the Internet is TCP. :D. UDP just an option.

Comment: You should know that UDP sends datagrams to the recipient whether they receive them or not.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are pointing to some default protocol. Its' not that, Whenever you start an application let say HTTP server, the server's internal has code to open a socket(which can be TCP or UDP), since `HTTP:80` is a TCP protocol the `code` creates a TCP socket. Similarly for other network application it depends on their requirement what kind of transport layer protocol to use `(TCP Or UDP)`. Like a DNS client will create a UDP socket to connect to DNS server, since `DNS:53` is mostly over UDP. Both TCP and UDP have different use cases, advantages and disadvantages. Depending on there uses cases / advantages / disadvantages of UDP/TCP decision is taken to implement server using either of them.